# Mod_rewrite to 404 page if match not found

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hey I'm trying to do a mod-rewrite for search engine friendly URLs that resolve to a 404 page if the file isn't found. When I get it working for directories that don't resolve to a file (ie search/.php) because no match is found then it doesn't work when a match is found.

Basically I need it to work when you go to url/search/ if there is an index page and url/search/filename should resolve to filename.php inside of the search directory. Anyone know how to accomplish this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .? - [S2] #file not found, skip to 404
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule .? - [S1] #file found, ignore redirect to 404
RewriteRule (.*) 404.php?file=$1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) 404.php?file=$1 [L]
```

instead of all of those skips?